# How to make textfield auto-filled when incoming sms Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, sms

how can i intercept incoming sms in iOS. For instance, when you installing whatsapp/viber, they ask you for verification process which is they send you a sms, after you receive sms, the verification process automatically verified it and bring you to the next screen. How they do that? thank you.

[closed]

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by setting the `contentType` of the `textField` to `.oneTimeCode`

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextcontenttype/2980930-onetimecode)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access messages service on ios, because message API is under on iOS private API and hence you cannot perform autofill the OTP functionality in ios apps by reading the content body of text sms.

Comment: what if I want to fill the OTP on labels, 'cause I customized the otp screen. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

That is happen in android in ios dose not allow to access incoming message.
User must have to insert OTP manually